# how to bold a text in a row of table when it is unread and how to unbold when already read using javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to bold text in my row and unbold when its already click just like gmail messages. On a particular row, when the text is clicked the text of that row would get unbold.

```
<td ><a  href="/webmcr/birthverifyview/<?=$veri['rreg_transactcode']?>" class="stretched-link" style="text-decoration: none; color: black;"><?= $veri['rreg_transactcode'] ?></a></td>
                                                            <td><?= $veri['rb_fname'] ?> <?= $veri['rb_mname'] ?> <?= $veri['rb_lname'] ?> </td>
                                                            <td><?= $veri['rb_createdat'] ?></td>
```

here is the example of my row that I want to get bold and unbold when its open

Comment: I have put example snippet in answer. Try that approach

Comment: Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[mre]" and all their linked pages. We'd like to see your attempt to solve this. Currently it looks like you didn't try and want us to write code for you, or to find a tutorial for you, both of which are off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Bind **click Event** and on the **Event Handler function unbold the text** using CSS. Here is the example code:-

```js
const messageIds = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("messageIds"));
var messageIdsArr = messageIds ? Array.from(messageIds) : [];

document.querySelectorAll("td").forEach((td) => {
  // Check if message already read or not
  if (messageIdsArr.length && messageIdsArr.includes(td.getAttribute("id"))) {
    td.style.fontWeight = "normal";
  } else {
    td.addEventListener("click", removeBold);
  }
});

function removeBold(e) {
  const target = e.currentTarget;
  target.style.fontWeight = "normal";

  // Update the LocalStorage
  messageIdsArr.push(target.getAttribute("id"));
  localStorage.setItem("messageIds", JSON.stringify(messageIdsArr));
}
```

```css
td{
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
 <table>
  <thead></thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
       <td id="1">Message 1</td>
       <td id="2">Message 2</td>
       <td id="3">Message 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

**Unique Id** has given to each message. And then use **localStorage to store the id** of message that has been read. So, even on **page load**, the read message will not be bold.

Note that, the code **will not run on stackoverflow snippet** because localStorage is restricted in snippet. But will work fine, outside of snippet. Hope it will be helpful.

Comment: Okay, thank you, the last question. What should I do if I want to remain unbolded even if I reload it?

Comment: then use localStorage. do you want me to update?

Comment: @hassim I have updated the code and put localStorage feature also so the message that is read will not be shown as bold even on page refresh